# Request apachenifi processor for POST request with form-data

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to POST one request from InvokeHTTP 1.20.0 using nifi processor. But whatever setting I change processor doesnt throw any error but still its not requesting to the server.  Here is the setting which i have kept

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

[image: Full Screenshot]
[image: ReplaceText Processor Config]

Comment: where is data located that you want to POST as x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html

> When the HTTP Method is POST, dynamic properties with the property name in the form of `post:form:<NAME>`, where the  will be the form data name, will be used to fill out the `multipart form parts`.

so, `post:form:<NAME>` could be used for `multipart/form-data` content type

and you want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

format of http body should be `parm1=Value1&parm2=Value2`

before calling invokeHttp use replaceText to build correct flowfile content:

```js
param1=value1&param2=value2
```

then use invokehttp with

```
Send Message Body = true
Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

ensure to unset any 'multipart' properties

Comment: In replace Text what would be the Search Value. I have edited my question. What I am doing wrong as after using replacetext I am getting key as { match_id: '' }

Comment: in ReplaceText you can specify `Replacement Strategy = Always Replace`  `Evaluation Mode = Entire text` - this will replace whole content with replacement value expression. in your case you should get in result `match_id=...`.

Comment: that didnt worked..

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: I was not getting data in invokeHttp processor

Comment: do you know what parameters you have to send in body? where you are taking values for them? do you have body example that works ? have you tried to specify flow-file content statically (without expressions) ?